# Limit of $\alpha^{2^n}$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I would appreciate if anyone could point out any possible mistakes in my arguments below.

Suppose we have $\alpha^{2^n}$ where $\alpha$ is a constant in $\mathbb{R}$. We consider two cases; either $\alpha\in(0,1)$ or $\alpha>1$.

For the first case: the limit $\alpha^{2^n}$ is zero as $n\to\infty$.

For the second case the limit of $\alpha^{2^n}$ is infinity as $n\to\infty$.

Both arguments can be justified using the fact that for any constants $x$ and $y$, we have $x^y=\exp(y\ln(x))$. Hence, we can write $$\alpha^{2^n}=\exp(2^n\ln(\alpha))=\exp(\exp(n\ln(2))\ln(\alpha)).$$

Note that if $\alpha\in(0,1)$ then $\ln(\alpha)<0$.

More explicitly for the first case, we can say:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(n\ln(2))=+\infty.$$ Let $\ln(\alpha)=-b$ for a positive constant $b$. So,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(-b\exp(n\ln(2)))=0.$$

Comment: Apart from not dealing with $\alpha=1$ (which, I know, is obvious, but you can't simply ignore it), this seems fine to me.

Comment: Since $m=2^n$ approaches $\infty$ as long as $n$ does, the problem is really not different from the simpler looking $\lim \alpha^m$ as $m \to \infty.$